# Chrome:cookie removed when user leaves page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, cookies, forms-authentication, payment-gateway

I have an ASP.NET MVC1 site where the user is logged in. He is logged in because he has a cookie ".ASPXAUTH" with a token value in it.

For payments the Users gets redirected to a payment provider. He is redirected to my site when he completed the payment process.

This usually was fine but since the 29th of june I got a lot of users who dont have a cookie when they get redirected to our site.

I cant reproduce this behaviour but I see a pattern: Most users that have lost the cookie have the recent version(20.0.1132.47) of Chrome on Windows.

Has anybody had issues like this in the last couple of days? I have no idea what the reason might be, but I suspect it to be a setting of Chrome that is changed now by lots of users or an addon that changes something.

**EDIT**

The cookie created by forms authentication is a session cookie. May be some browsers changed the way they detect a session. If I have a session cookie, close the browser and reopen it I still have the cookie.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608362/chrome-losing-cookies ?